# Simple java array string algorithms question

Tags: java

My two functions `isSorted` and `hasDuplicate` created below should work, right? My test class for the assignment wasn't working. The instructions for both are in the comments below. `isSorted` returns `true` if the string array is sorted alphabetically, and `false` - if not. `hasDuplicate` returns `true` if there's at least one set of duplicate strings and `false` - if not.

```java
public class CheckStrings {
    /**
     * Returns true if the Strings in w appear in sorted order
     * (alphabetical order) and false otherwise.
     * 
     * @param w the array of Strings to check
     * @return true if the Strings in w appear in sorted order
     * and false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isSorted(String[] w) {
        boolean bob = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length-1; i++)
        {
            if (w[i].compareTo(w[i+1]) >= 0)
            {
                bob = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bob = false;
                i = w.length + 50;
            }
        }
        
        return bob;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns true if at least one String in w appears more than once
     * and false otherwise.
     * 
     * @param w the array of Strings to check
     * @return true if at least one String in w appears more than once
     * and false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean hasDuplicate(String[] w) {
        boolean bob = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length-1; i++)
        {
            if (w[i].equals(w[i+1]))
            {
                bob = true;
                i = w.length + 50;
            }
            else
            {
                bob = false;
                
            }
        }
        return bob;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? what/where is your test class? please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hasDuplicate should initialize bob with false (empty array has no duplicates). It assumes that the array is sorted. Else-parts are not needed. `i = w.length + 50;` can be replaced with `break;`

Comment: What is the message, that the failed tests are throwing?

Answer (score 1):

Submit this for your homework:

```
public static boolean isSorted(String[] w) {
   return Arrays.stream(w).reduce("",(a, b) -> a == null || a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? null : b) != null;
}

public static boolean hasDuplicate(String[] w) {
   return Arrays.stream(w).distinct().count() == w.length;
}
```

And who is Bob?

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class CheckStrings {

    private CheckStrings() {
    }

    public static boolean isSorted(String... w) {
        if (w == null || w.length == 0)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0, j = w.length - 1; j < w.length; i++, j++)
            if (w[i].compareToIgnoreCase(w[j]) > 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean hasDuplicate(String... w) {
        if (w == null || w.length == 0)
            return false;

        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();

        for (String str : w)
            if (!unique.add(str.toLowerCase()))
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
String[] arr = {"a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"};
System.out.println(CheckStrings.isSorted(arr));     // true
System.out.println(CheckStrings.hasDuplicate(arr)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not allowed yet to use Java 8 Stream API, implementation of the `isSorted` and `hasDuplicate` may look as follows:

```java
public static boolean isSorted(String[] w) {
    if (null == w || w.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < w.length-1; i++) {
        if (w[i].compareTo(w[i+1]) > 0) {  // or compareToIgnoreCase if case insensitive is ok
            return false;
        }
    }
        
    return true;
}

public static boolean hasDuplicate(String[] w) {
    if (null == w || w.length < 2) return false;
        
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length-1; i++) {
        String s = w[i];        // if case-insensitive lookup needed use s = w[i].toLowerCase();
        if (set.contains(s)) {
            return true;
        }
        set.add(s);
    }
    return false;
}
```